# Extract text between double square brackets in Python

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string that may look like this:

```
"[[Category:Political culture]]\n\n          [[Category:Political ideologies]]\n\n"
```

How do I extract the categories and put them into a list?
I'm having a hard time getting the regular expression to work.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> str = "[[Category:Political culture]]\n\n          [[Category:Political ideologies]]\n\n"
>>> re.findall(r'Category:([^\[\]]*)', str)
['Political culture', 'Political ideologies']
>>> re.findall(r'Category:[^\[\]]*', str)
['Category:Political culture', 'Category:Political ideologies']
```

By default `re.findall` will print only the strings which are matched by the pattern present inside a capturing group. If no capturing group was present, then only the `findall` function would return the matches in list. So in our case , this `Category:` matches the string `category:` and this `([^\[\]]*)` would capture any character but not of `[` or `]` zero or more times. Now the findall function would return the characters which are present inside the group index 1.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I have a question though: Why is 'Category' before the square brackets? Shouldn't it appear in between?

Comment: could you provide an example which replicate the above?

Comment: No, it is working, I just meant: Could you explain the regular expression to me, because I don't really understand how it works :)

Comment: You mean the first one?

Comment: Yeah sure. What I don't understand is why the word "Category" appears first in the regular expression. Shouldn't it appear in the middle: "([^\[Category:*\]]" ?

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the explanation of the regex used by Avinash in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128143/extract-text-between-double-square-brackets-in-python/27128161#27128161):

`Category:([^\[\]]*)` consists of several parts:

- `Category:` which matches the text "Category:"
- `(...)` is a capture group meaning roughly "the expression inside this group is a block that I want to extract"
- `[^...]` is a negated set which means "do not match any characters in this set".
- `\[` and `\]` match "[" and "]" in the text respectively.
- `*` means "match zero or more of the preceding regex defined items"

Where I have used `...` to indicate that I removed some characters that were not important for the explanation.

So putting it all together, the regex does this:

Finds "Category:" and then matches any number (including zero) characters after that that are not the excluded characters "[" or "]". When it hits an excluded character it stops and the text matched by the regex inside the `(...)` part is returned. So the regex does not actually look for "[[" or "]]" as you might expect and so will match even if they are left out. You could force it to look for the double square brackets at the beginning and end by changing it to `\[\[Category:([^\[\]]*)\]\]`.

For the second regex, `Category:[^\[\]]*`, the capture group `(...)` is excluded, so Python returns everything matched which includes "Category:".

Answer (score 0):

Python code:

```
s = "[[Category:Political culture]]\n\n          [[Category:Political ideologies]]\n\n"
cats = [line.strip().strip("[").strip("]") for line in s.splitlines() if line]
print(cats)
```

Output:

```
['Category:Political culture', 'Category:Political ideologies']
```